# FirebaseFirestore cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

Im struggling with the following issue and I cant find a solution. I have multi module project. I set up all the modules and dependencies but im still getting this error for firestore: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.google.firebase.firestore

My DI setup is following

FirebaseDiModule(part of the firestore module)

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object FirebaseDiModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideFirebaseAuth(): FirebaseAuth {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideFirestoreFirebase(): FirebaseFirestore {
        return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideUserFirebaseDataSource(
        firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore,
        firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
    ): UserFirestoreDataSource {
        return UserFirestoreDataSource(
            firebaseFirestore = firebaseFirestore,
            firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth,
        )
    }
}
```

UserFirestoreDataSource (part of the firebase module)

```
class UserFirestoreDataSource @Inject constructor(
   private val firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore,
   private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
)
```

Then I have authentication module which is beasicly a feature module contaning jetpack compose and viewmodel's.

The ViewModel i use is set as this:

```
@HiltViewModel
class OnBoardingViewModel @Inject constructor(
    userFirestoreDataSource: UserFirestoreDataSource,
) : ViewModel() {
```

The authentication module is added to the app module where I use the OnBoardingViewModel and composables.

In the app module I have this:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class AppController : Application()
```

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity()
```

When I run the project I get the following error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements AppController_GeneratedInjector,
```

But this error only occurs when I add @HiltViewModel annotation to the OnBoardingViewModel. Im really frustrated by this problem and I cant figure it out what am I doing wrong.

There is nothing to try because it's a DI setup.

Comment: were you able to figure this one out?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a @HiltViewModel class and annotate it with the `@HiltViewModel` annotation.

here is an example code:

```
@HiltViewModel
class OnBoardingViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    userFirestoreDataSource: UserFirestoreDataSource
) : ViewModel() {
  //ViewModel code
}
```

it's like telling DI (@ViewModelInject) hey this is a ViewModel class inject the necessary dependencies into the ViewModel

Comment: If you read the question again you can see that I already declared HiltViewModel